# Тире, двоеточие, запятая? Почему при выборе знака в БСП не определяется вид интонации?

Tags: пунктуация

В БСП основным средством связи предложений является ИНТОНАЦИЯ, но при выборе знаков препинания мы эту интонацию НИКАК НЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕМ, НЕ НАЗЫВАЕМ И НЕ АНАЛИЗИРУЕМ. Вместо этого проводится анализ семантических отношений между предложениями, входящими в БСП, что в конечном итоге не приводит к однозначному решению и вызывает постоянные вопросы. А если попробовать решить задачу с помощью интонации? Рассмотрим такое решение на конкретном примере, который недавно здесь обсуждался:  Не спи (?) замерзнешь!

1) В БСП применяется 4 ВИДА ИНТОНАЦИИ: перечислительная (запятая для однородных предложений), присоединительная (запятая или тире), разделительная (тире), пояснительная (двоеточие).

2) Не спи, замерзнешь. Это ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНТОНАЦИЯ, взаимообусловленность предложений не обозначена (хотя она и существует). Еще вариант: Не спи, а то замерзнешь (только запятая). Здесь использован дополнительный структурный элемент А ТО, конкретизирующий отношения между предложениями.

3) Не спи – замерзнешь! Это тоже ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНТОНАЦИЯ ПРИ НАЛИЧИИ ПАУЗЫ, причинно-следственные отношения обозначены.

4) Не спи: замерзнешь! Это ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНТОНАЦИЯ (с увеличенной паузой), причинно-следственные отношения не только обозначены, но и указано их НАПРАВЛЕНИЕ: причина-следствие. Двоеточие фактически не применяется в этом примере, так как направленность связи и так понятна.

Таким образом, автор может выбрать любой вариант и объяснить свое решение всем желающим это услышать. **Итак, при наличии причинно-следственных отношений мы можем использовать следующие знаки: универсальную запятую, более информативное тире или разъясняющее двоеточие.**

Comment: 3) Не спи – замерзнешь! Для меня это нонсенс. Я это читаю с интонацией "если не спать - так замерзнешь". Потом буксую, задумываюсь и понимаю, что получается чушь. Такие предложения называются дефектными - когда смысл не сразу угадывается.

Comment: Тат,а как вы поставите знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Comment: Среди ССП выделяется группа предложений со значением АЛЬТЕРНАТИВНОЙ МОТИВАЦИИ.  Эти предложения обозначают связь двух ситуаций, одна из которых нежелательна для говорящего или его адресата (союзы А ТО, А НЕ ТО, ИНАЧЕ). Например: Уходите в комнаты, а то простудитесь. Не спи, а то (иначе) замерзнешь. В нашем случае (Не спи - замерзнешь!) фактически пропущен альтернативный союз А ТО, на его месте стоит тире.

Answer (score 1):

Вера, такие примеры, как "Не спи – замерзнешь!" носят явно разговорный характер. Пунктуация разговорной речи недостаточна разработана. Конечно же, в некоторых случаях можно опираться на аналогичные конструкции литературного языка, тем не менее, я бы не рекомендовал бы ставить двоеточие в таких конструкциях( конечно двоеточие тоже можно). Двоеточие придает оттенок книжности, официальности. Лучше в таких примерах обойтись запятой или тире.

Comment: Эта методика подходит для любых случаев,  она универсальна, так как имеет грамматическое обоснование. А вот "оттенки книжности и официальности" - это эмпирический термин, в то время как  грамматика  - наука точная. Это предложение несложное для анализа,  грамматика же изучает самые разнообразные конструкции, в том числе фразеологизованного вида. Определив вид предложения, вы без труда можете выбрать и обосновать знаки препинания. Другими словами, пунктуация - это приложение к грамматике, ее не надо специально разрабатывать.

Comment: Вера, я говорю, что в разговорном стиле лучше ставить запятую или тире, а не то,что сама конструкция не разрешает ставить двоеточие.  Что касается разговорного стиля, то пунктуация там не достаточна разработана.

Comment: Я поняла, Серж. Но, может быть, вы ответите на вопрос про интонацию: почему  не определяется вид интонации, если это основной вид связи. Или интонация в БСП со знаками препинания никак не связана, они существуют отдельно друг от друга? К чему поштучное решение для каждого предложения, всякие домыслы и поиски причины, если можно всё это сделать в общем виде, просто определив вид интонации и привязав к ней знак препинания.

Comment: Потому что на интонацию нужно чутье, а у большинства людей его нет - как музыкального слуха. Вы давно слушали, как люди стихи читают?